# Json to Map in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Sorry for asking stupid question. I just have lack of experience with Json.
So, I have JsObject like:

```
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2",  "field3":"value3"}
```

Can I somehow convert this to Map[String,String] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

val json = Json.parse("""{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2",  "field3":"value3"}""")
val map = json.as[Map[String, String]]
```